# What is the difference between a "Customer Community Login" license, and a "Customer Community" license?

Tags: community, licenses

Among the various Salesforce User Licenses, there exist the following Community-specific types.

- Customer Community
- Customer Community Login
- Partner Community
- Partner Community Login

What is the difference between the "Customer Community" and "Customer Community Login" licenses?  Same question applies to the "Partner Community" and "Partner Community Login" licenses.

I think that the difference is related to the two ways that Community licenses can be purchased, either as a block of "User Accounts", or as a block of "Logins per Month".

I'm guessing that the "Customer/Partner Community Login" license type is related to the "Logins per Month" purchase option, but would like confirmation of this by anyone in the know.

Thank you!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm not easily finding a confirming link, but your guess is correct - the "Login" licenses are for logins-per-month pricing, and the plain "Community" licenses are for named-user licensing. I just took a training on Communities implementation where this was covered.

Comment: If you just had the training, that's good enough for me!  Thank you very much for the confirmation!

Comment: @VivekM.Chawla, if I have 10 Customer Community Login licenses available, does that mean I can assign those ten licenses to infinite number of users, out of which only the first 10 logins per month be entertained? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I still dint get, what does it mean ? is there any data accessibility difference ? because in both type of licencing user must log in before accessing their portal. I did find the difference any where even if we talk about high volume customer portal user and authenticated website user I dint find any difference. Can someone help to understand the actual difference ?

Answer (score 10):

Here is the nice resource which describes communities licenses in details:
https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2014/02/salesforce-communities-licenses.html

> Customer Community and Partner Community licenses are offered as
>   member-based or login-based:
>
> A user with a member-based license can log in to communities as often
>   as he wants A user with a member-based license consumes one license
>   per community he is member of A user with a login-based license
>   consumes a login each time he logs in to the community
>
> **How logins get calculated?**
>
> First, let’s explore how login-based licenses work. With login-based
>   licenses, you purchase an amount of monthly logins for your members.
>   For instance, if you purchased 20K logins, you can use 20K logins
>   every month. The logins consumed reset to 0 at the end of each
>   calendar month.
>
> A login is consumed each time an external user submits his username
>   and password to log into the community (or legacy portal). The same
>   rule applies if the user is accessing Communities from a mobile
>   device. The mobile app consumes a login each time it requests a
>   refresh token.
>
> An org-level perm lets you control the user session duration. This
>   setting applies to all users, external and internal.

Comment: What's the maximum session duration? I would like to know how much would it cost me for users that go to the platform on a daily basis

Comment: For daily use, member-based licensing will always be much less expensive. Up to 3 logins/month, a user will cost less with login-based licensing.